# seaborn.heatmap() plot timestamp with milliseconds

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

here is df.isnull().head() :

```
                     meter_20201_p  meter_20202_p  meter_20203_p  meter_20204_p  ...  meter_20207_p  meter_20208_p  meter_20209_p  meter_20210_p
timestamp                                                                        ...                                                            
2022-10-19 00:00:00          False          False          False          False  ...          False          False          False          False
2022-10-19 00:00:05          False          False          False          False  ...          False          False          False          False
2022-10-19 00:00:10          False          False          False          False  ...          False          False          False          False
2022-10-19 00:00:15          False          False          False          False  ...          False          False          False          False
2022-10-19 00:00:20          False          False          False          False  ...          False          False          False          False
```

here is my code

```
def visualize_missing_values(df : pd.DataFrame,outputFilenamePrefix):
# Create a heatmap for missing values

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
df.index = df.index.round('s')

print(df.isnull().head())

colors = [ '#001470','#FE5716']
# Create a custom colormap
cmap_custom = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("custom_cmap", colors)

sns.heatmap(df.isnull(), cbar=False, cmap=cmap_custom)
plt.title('Missing Values Heatmap')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(outputFilenamePrefix+"_heatmap.png", bbox_inches="tight")
```

here is the plot results :
[image]

here a simple example to reproduce the issue :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# Sample Data
data = {
    'meter_20201_p': [None, 1, None, 4, 5],
    'meter_20202_p': [1, 2, None, 4, 5],
    'meter_20203_p': [1, 2, 3, 4, None]
}
index = pd.to_datetime(['2022-10-19 00:00:00.123', '2022-10-19 00:00:05.567', '2022-10-19 00:00:10.890', '2022-10-19 00:00:15.234', '2022-10-19 00:00:20.567'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

# Round the timestamps
df.index = df.index.round('s')
print(df.isnull().head())

colors = ['#001470', '#FE5716']
cmap_custom = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("custom_cmap", colors)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.heatmap(df.isnull(), cbar=False, cmap=cmap_custom)
plt.title('Missing Values Heatmap')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

How can I round the timestamp in the plot? It seems to be done in the df.index but does not match the plot.

Comment: If you print your `df.index`, you will find `dtype='datetime64[ns]'`, so just add `.astype('datetime64[s]')` to your code `df.index = df.index.round('s')`

Comment: indeed thanks !!